# How to Prove that a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of functions converges uniformly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f\colon (0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is not identically $0$ and  $$\lim _{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0, $$ then does the  sequence  of functions  $\{f_n\}$ defined by $$f_n(x) = f(nx)$$  converge uniformly to the zero function?

Comment: On which set do you ask uniform convergence? If it's $(0,+\infty)$ it's not true, taking $f(x)=1/x$.

Comment: Yes from (0, oo) but can you explain me Why its not true ?

Comment: It satisfies the first condition, but $\sup_{x\in (0,+\infty}|\frac 1{nx}-0|$ is not finite.

Comment: Ok , thanks alot

Comment: (-1) [Please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, we never have the uniform convergence on $(0,+\infty)$, since if $f(x_0)\neq 0$ then $\sup_{x>0}|f(nx)|\geq \left|f\left(n\frac{x_0}n\right)\right|=|f(x_0)|>0$.