# puntual and uniformly convergence of a succession of function

Tags: real-analysis

$f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function not all null so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$.
I have to study pointwise and uniformly convergence on $(0,+\infty)$ of $f_n(x)=f(nx)$ and $g_n(x)=f({x \over n})$

Comment: Am I guessing you right?

Comment: (-1) Please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Duplicate: [How to Prove that a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of functions converges uniformly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126876).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously $\forall x\in R^+$  we have $ 0=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}g_n(x). $ Fix some $a$ with $f(a)\ne 0$. For each $n>0$ let $x_n=a/n$.We have $f_n(a_n)=f(a). $ Therefore $\forall n>0 \exists  x(f_n(x)=f(a))$. So $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ as $n\to \infty$.Similarly, let $b_n=n a. $ We have $g_n(b_n)=f(a) . $ Therefore $\forall n>0 \exists x (g_n(x)=f(a)) . $  So $g_n$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: Why  the negative vote?

Comment: (+1) Probably because you answered a no-effort question.